# In django, any user can block any user, if they are blocked they cant see the posts of the blocked users and cant find them too

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

in my django i have made so that users can follow each other and will get posts of the users they follow. I now want to implement a blocking system  so any user can block another user and the blocked users cannot see the profile or posts of the user who blocked them

My models.py:

```
class post(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_pics', null=True, blank=True)
video = models.FileField(upload_to='post_videos', null=True, blank=True)
content = models.TextField()
likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes', blank=True)
date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

objects = postManager()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-date_posted', 'title']

def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse ('blog-home')

def total_likes(self):
    return self.likes.count()

class UserProfileManager(models.Manager):
use_for_related_fields = True
def all(self):
    qs = self.get_queryset().all()
    try:
        if self.instance:
            qs = qs.exclude(user=self.instance)
    except:
        pass
    return qs

def toggle_follow(self, user, to_toggle_user):
    user_profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    if to_toggle_user in user_profile.following.all():
       user_profile.following.remove(to_toggle_user)
       added = False
    else:
       user_profile.following.add(to_toggle_user)
       added = True
    return added

def is_following(self, user, followed_by_user):
    user_profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    if created:
        return False
    if followed_by_user in user_profile.following.all():
        return True
    return False


class UserProfile(models.Model):
user      = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='owner', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
following = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name='followed_by')

objects = UserProfileManager()

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.following.all().count())

def get_following(self):
    users = self.following.all()
    return users.exclude(username=self.user.username)
```

Comment: sir, would you help me on this. @TheGoldKnight23

Comment: I feel like your asking for code to do it for you, which is not what SO is for. I would try and solve the problem yourself and then come back with specific issues of 'Why does this not work'

Comment: no sir, i just don't ask the code, i just want to know. I will do a blocklist by myself for each and every user , i'm asking for how could i get the real functionality of blocking, like if i block you i wiil not found you, not getting the posts, like other social media do.@TheGoldKnight23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there maybe two different approach to that, first you have a custom user model or profile. so add a new field to this model, which is a may_to_many field to 'self' (user model itself), and it is the blocked users id holder.
its simple to implement.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    .......
    blocked_users = many_to_many_field(User, related_name="blocked_by")
```

the second idea is to create a new model, has a foreign key to User model, and also has a many to many relation to User model again.

```
class Blocked(models.Model):
    user = foreign_key_field(User, related_name="blocked_users", ....)
     users = many_to_many_field(User, related_name="blocked_by" )
```

so you will be able to call like this:

```
user.blocked_users.users.all()
```

now you have access one users blocked_users, so by using filter on query_set, ignore blocked_users for each other.

```
from django.db.models import Q
# to ignore user X's blocked users posts
blocked_users = User.objects.get(username=X).blocked_users.users.all()
Post.objects.filter(~Q(author__in=blocked_users))
```

Comment: understood! but let me grab you a example, if i blocked you in instagram i will not see your posts and you will not see my posts. now if i want to search you i could not get you because i blocked you. how to do this function@MahdiFirouzjah

Comment: do the same filtering on any queryset will give you what you want

Comment: You have a mistake here
usres = many_to_many_field(User, related_name="blocked_by" )

# usres will generate an error, because it doesn't match with "users"

Comment: that was a typo